# Catching a pop-up file download with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

I'm using puppeteer to automate the downloading of a `.csv` from a human facing website.

The file I want is downloaded from a uniquely generated URL, so I'm using using `page.click()` events to trigger the download. The problem I'm having is that the file is downloaded as a pop-up download with the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header, and I can't figure out how to catch the data.

I've tried setting an event handler for `browser.on('targetcreated'...` which successfully triggers when the file is downloaded, however, in that event handler I'm unable to get much info (or the data) because my attempts in getting the new target's page (`let newpage = await target.page();`) fail with

```
(node:27389) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error (Page.enable): Target closed.
```

I think this is from the short-lived nature of the new target (it is a small file) and the promise does not resolve before the target is closed.

I've also tried things like handlers for the `response` event and request interception, but since these are scoped to the page, and technically a new page is opening up, they don't seem to be the right course of action. It seems like what I need is to be able to set global style event handlers for a browser instead of a page, or figure out why I can't get the page from my new target. Any help appreciated. Below is a copy of the caught target created event in case that helps

```
Target {
  _targetInfo:
   { targetId: '8E6B6B77483AE2F37E7DDD51739B220E',
     type: 'page',
     title: '',
     url: 'https://example.com/cca21744-72f0-49b3-a048-12348d1bd97c/exports/af81008a-0547-4e62-aa28-a3228bc2b785/outputResource',
     attached: false,
     openerId: 'A66C8D5FD6206E6FE55139B2440B1CE5',
     browserContextId: 'C2D9840857DC03C38B1114F9008F3638' },
  _browserContext:
   BrowserContext {
     _events: {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _connection:
      Connection {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 4,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:54439/devtools/browser/ebf728ce-2bb2-4d20-9c3f-4868ae7768c3',
        _lastId: 126,
        _callbacks: Map {},
        _delay: 5.240825308449115,
        _transport: [WebSocketTransport],
        _sessions: [Map],
        _closed: false },
     _browser:
      Browser {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _ignoreHTTPSErrors: false,
        _defaultViewport: [Object],
        _process: [ChildProcess],
        _screenshotTaskQueue: [TaskQueue],
        _connection: [Connection],
        _closeCallback: [Function: gracefullyCloseChrome],
        _defaultContext: [Circular],
        _contexts: Map {},
        _targets: [Map] },
     _id: null },
  _targetId: '8E6B6B77483AE2F37E7DDD51739B220E',
  _sessionFactory: [Function],
  _ignoreHTTPSErrors: false,
  _defaultViewport: { width: 800, height: 600 },
  _screenshotTaskQueue: TaskQueue { _chain: Promise { undefined } },
  _pagePromise: null,
  _initializedCallback: [Function],
  _initializedPromise: Promise { true },
  _closedCallback: [Function],
  _isClosedPromise: Promise { <pending> },
  _isInitialized: true }
```

Comment: As a work around, I was able to make progress by figuring out the URL, copying the cookies and using `request` to make the request directly so that I could catch the result.